# Is a `mut` on a moved function parameter leaking implementation details to the function's API?

Tags: rust

I am new to Rust, just reading the 2nd edition of the programming in Rust book. I was wondering about the below but couldn't find an answer so far.

When defining a function, you can move some of the parameters. You can also declare them `mut` (without a reference) if you intend to mutate them within the function.

For the caller, this `mut` does not seem to have any significance, however. They have just moved ownership, and what happens to the data after that point is not their concern, is it?

So, is it right to say that a `mut` along with a moved parameter is actually not part of the function's API? Instead, it is leaking implementation details of that function to its signature.

Thanks for helping me understand this better.

Regards,
Alex

Comment: Just want to mention that the Rust generated documentation doesn't include the `mut` when documenting the function. Check out `Vec`'s [`into_boxed_slice(self)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.into_boxed_slice) for example, which uses `mut self` in the [source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec/mod.rs.html#995).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right that the `mut` does not change the interface in any way. The function pointer types of these two functions

```
fn foo(s: String);
fn bar(mut s: String);
```

is `fn(String)` – whether the binding is mutable is not part of the function type. Since the types are considered identical with and without the `mut`, the `mut` isn't any meaningful part of the API.

Also note that a function can mutate any value that it receives ownership of, regardless of whether the corresponding paramter is marked as `mut`. If you have an immutable variable binding, you can always move it into a mutable binding, e.g.

```
fn foo(s: String) {
    let mut s = s;
    s.push_str("glonk");
}
```

So the `mut` in the signature is neither part of the API, nor does it actually tell you much about what the function is doing.

Comment: Notice with respect to "it receives ownership of": The function always receives ownership of its parameters. A `&T` or `&mut T` is just another type. This means the example can be expanded to `fn foo(s: &str)`, where the function takes ownership of the `&str` (which is easy to do, because `&T` is `Copy`). As in the example above, the function is able to either do `fn foo(mut s: &str)` in the signature or `let mut s: &str = s` inside the body.

Comment: @user2722968 Unless you define your function as `fn foo(ref s: String)`, in which case the caller will pass in a `String`, but the function can only access an `&String`. I guess the answer to this is "Why would you do that?"

Comment: Unless you define your function as `fn foo(ref mut s: String)`, to confuse everybody